# How to select data from a JSON in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that reads CSV data from S3 and converts it to JSON.
Code :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const bucket = 'awslambdabuckets';
const objectkey = 'claimant_record.csv';
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey };
const results = [];

exports.handler = function (event, ctx, callback) {
    try {
        const file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        file
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function (data) {
                results.push(data);
                // console.log(results)
                callback(null, results);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                // console.log(results);
                callback(null, results);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        // console.log(err);
        callback(Error(err));
    }
    
};
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "678980",
    "fName": "Michelle",
    "lName": "Humbert",
    "mName": "K.",
  },
  {
    "ID": "705264",
    "fName": "John",
    "lName": "Turner",
    "mName": "NULL",
  },
  {
    "ID": "720367",
    "fName": "Timothy",
    "lName": "Labonte",
    "mName": "E.",
  }
]
```

Problem: How do I access only the ID of each customer in JSON?

Steps I have tried:

```
     callback(Error(err));
    }
    
};
for (var result of results) {
     console.log(result.ID)
}
```

Output: `Null`

Comment: Are you able to get an array of objects? And where are you trying to run the loop?

Comment: After callback(Error(err)); }.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make changes to the code. You don't need to use try/catch when you are using cbs.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const bucket = 'awslambdabuckets';
const objectkey = 'claimant_record.csv';
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: objectkey };
const results = [];

exports.handler = function (event, ctx, callback) {
        const file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        file
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', function (data) {
                results.push(data);
                // console.log(results)
                callback(null, results);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                // console.log(results);
                // once you get the results
                // try looping here.
                for (const result of results) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
                callback(null, results);
            })
            .on('error', () => {
                // catch errors here
            })

};
```

The reason your o/p was null, it was executed before the data from the stream is completed. This is a common problem, so make sure you put things in a manner when you can receive results in order.